# How do I remove this white line from my bootstrap navbar and change the text colors?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have been playing around with bootstrap so build me a small personal page where I have a navbar that looks like this:

```
<body>
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top navbar-shrink">
<div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header page-scroll">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>

        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#home">Jon Snow</a>
    </div>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li class="page-scroll">
                <a href="#about">About Me</a>
            </li>
            <li class="page-scroll">
                <a href="#work">Work</a>
            </li>
            <li class="page-scroll">
                <a href="#blog">Blog</a>
            </li>
            <li class="page-scroll">
                <a href="#contact">Contact Me</a>
        </ul>
    </div>
   </div>
  </nav>
</body>
```

And its styled as follows:

```
body {
   background-color:#2c3e50;
 }

.navbar-fixed-top.navbar-shrink {
   color:white;
   padding: 10px 0;
   background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
 }
```

But I get a white line at the navbar that looks like this:
[image]

How do I remove the white line and change the colors of the items in the Navbar to white?

Here is a [JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/15690/).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here are the rules you can apply to remove borders (on all viewports) and change the color of the `li` items.

See working example Snippet.

```css
body,
html {
  background: #2c3e50;
}
.navbar.navbar-default {
  padding: 10px 0;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
  border: none;
}
.navbar.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a,
.navbar.navbar-default .navbar-brand {
  color: white;
}
.navbar.navbar-default .navbar-collapse {
  border: none;
  box-shadow: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top navbar-shrink">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header page-scroll">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>

      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#home">Jon Snow</a>
    </div>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li class="page-scroll">
          <a href="#about">About Me</a>
        </li>
        <li class="page-scroll">
          <a href="#work">Work</a>
        </li>
        <li class="page-scroll">
          <a href="#blog">Blog</a>
        </li>
        <li class="page-scroll">
          <a href="#contact">Contact Me</a>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: This one worked perfectly compared to other answers so I am going to accept this. Although @Damon answer is great I had small issues using it with fullPage.js

Answer (score 2):

Just add this to your styling:

```
.navbar {  border: none!important; }
```

Bootstrap nav has a default border.

And the color:

```
.navbar-default .navbar-nav li a { color: #fff; }
```

Comment: Uhm, sorry, Damon answered before me with the exact same thing, mark his as good answer if it helped!

Answer (score 0):

This guy right here:

```
.navbar-default {
    border-color: #e7e7e7;
}
```

Change that to `none` or the same color as your background color. Should do the trick.

**EDIT**

Sorry, I missed the second part of your question. This should set your text color in the nav bar:

```
.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a {
    color: #fff;
}
```

Then you'll need a `hover` rule (or any other state):

```
.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a {
    color: red;
}
```

Comment: The first part didn't quite work. It needed the .navbar selected as well apparently.

Answer (score 0):

The line is caused by the following CSS in Bootstrap

```
.navbar-default {
  background-color: #f8f8f8;
  border-color: #e7e7e7;
}
```

Overwrite this `border-color` with any color or no color you want.

For this links change the color with this

```
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a{
    color:**your color** !important;
}
```

You can do the hover, active, focus and visited colors for the links like this

```
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:hover{color: **your color** !important;}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:active{color: **your color** !important;}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:focus{color: **your color** !important;}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:visited{color: **your color** !important;}
```

Hope that helps!